# foreach results in an array, how can I get the value of element instead of an array?

Tags: javascript, php, xml, rss

I'm a inexpert PHP user trying to generate an XML RSS Document,
Using a PHP class [RSS_PHP RSS Parser](http://rssphp.net/examples/)

The `foreach` returns 30 `<items>` which is good because that's that's the number of items on the xml source, but when trying to get the value of `<title>` the result it's an  `Array`

I don't know what I'm missing or what I need to change to get the value of the `<title>` from [source](http://rss.tvguide.com/breakingnews) instead of an array.

Any help will be very appreciated, thanks.

```js
<?php 
require_once 'rss_php.php';
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', true); //set document header content type to be XML

 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"></rss>');
 $xml->addAttribute('version', '2.0');

 $rss = new rss_php;
    $rss->load('http://rss.tvguide.com/breakingnews');
    $items = $rss->getItems();
 
 $channel = $xml->addChild('channel'); //add channel node
 $title = $channel->addChild('title','Channel Title Here'); //title of the feed
 $link = $channel->addChild('link','http://www.zstreambox.com'); //feed site
 $description = $channel->addChild('description','Channel description here'); //feed description
 $language = $channel->addChild('language','en-us'); //language
 $ttl = $channel->addChild('ttl','120'); //time
 $image = $channel->addChild('image'); //add atom node
 $url = $image->addChild('url','http://static.tvgcdn.net/www/img/tvguide-feed-logo.png'); //add channel image
 $title = $image->addChild('title','ZSB: Breaking News'); //add channel title
 $link = $image->addChild('link','http://www.zstreambox.com'); //add channel link


 foreach($items as $index => $item) {  
  $item = $channel->addChild('item'); //add item node
  $title = $item->addChild('title', $item['title']); //add title node

}

 echo $xml->asXML();

?>
```

```html
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Channel Title Here</title>
<link>http://www.zstreambox.com</link>
<description>Channel description here</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<ttl>120</ttl>
<image>...</image>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

The example provided by the PHP Class website is:

```html
<?php
require_once 'rss_php.php';    

    $rss = new rss_php;
    $rss->load('http://digg.com/rss/index.xml');
    $items = $rss->getItems();

    $html = '';
    foreach($items as $index => $item) {
        $html .= '<p><a href="'.$item['link'].'" title="'.$item['title'].'"><strong>'.$item['title'].'</strong></a><br />
                    '.$item['description'].'<br />
                    Submitted by: <a href="'.$item['digg:submitter']['digg:userimage'].'">'.$item['digg:submitter']['digg:username'].'</a> :: '.$item['pubDate'].'<br />
                    Diggs: '.$item['digg:diggCount'].' :: <em>Category: '.$item['digg:category'].'</em>
                    </p>';
    }
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Digg Front Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
echo $html;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to include the corrected and working code in case anyone need it
thanks to the amazing people who share and help on this awesome website

```html
<?php 
require_once 'rss_php.php';
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', true); //set document header content type to be XML

 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"></rss>');
 $xml->addAttribute('version', '2.0');

 $rss = new rss_php;
    $rss->load('http://rss.tvguide.com/breakingnews');
    $items = $rss->getItems();
 
 $channel = $xml->addChild('channel'); //add channel node
 $title = $channel->addChild('title','Channel Title Here'); //title of the feed
 $link = $channel->addChild('link','http://www.zstreambox.com'); //feed site
 $description = $channel->addChild('description','Channel description here'); //feed description
 $language = $channel->addChild('language','en-us'); //language
 $ttl = $channel->addChild('ttl','120'); //time
 $image = $channel->addChild('image'); //add atom node
 $url = $image->addChild('url','http://static.tvgcdn.net/www/img/tvguide-feed-logo.png'); //add channel image
 $title = $image->addChild('title','ZSB: Breaking News'); //add channel title
 $link = $image->addChild('link','http://www.zstreambox.com'); //add channel link


 foreach($items as $index => $item) {        
     $xml_item = $channel->addChild('item'); //add item node
     $title = $xml_item->addChild('title', ''.$item['title'].''); 
     $description = $xml_item->addChild('description', ''. $item['description'] . '');
 }

 echo $xml->asXML();

?>
```

Comment: So, where does `title` come from?

Comment: not appending to the root element after you create it

Comment: @charlietfl thank you.. sorry to ask you, can you please give me more information on how to append to the root document? Thank you.

Comment: so if `<channel>` is the root element ... instead of `$xml->addChild` after that do `$channel->addChild`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you understand what's happening with `$item` variable in your `foreach`?

```
foreach($items as $index => $item) {        
    // here $item in a item of RSS feed
    $item = $xml->addChild('item'); //add item node
    // and here $item is an XML-node
    // and as it is an XML-node now - 
    // it doesn't have `title` or `description` property
    $title = $item->addChild('title', ''.['title'].''); //add title node    
    $description = $item->addChild('description', ''. ['description'] . ''); //add description
}
```

Proper code:

```
foreach($items as $index => $item) {        
    $xml_item = $xml->addChild('item'); //add item node
    $title = $xml_item->addChild('title', ''.$item['title'].''); 
    $description = $xml_item->addChild('description', ''. $item['description'] . '');
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, the explanation and the solution code, it works and you don't have an idea of how much you help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example from the [RSS parser](http://rssphp.net/examples/), each `$item` is an associative array with keys such as `title` and `description`. `['title']` is an array literal containing one string, `'title'`, if you want to access the title for an item, you would use `$item['title']` giving you something like:

```
$title = $item->addChild('title', $item['title']); //add title node
```

Comment: Thank you very much @mzulch  I replace the
' $title = $item->addChild('title', ''.['title'].''); //add title node ' for
' $title = $item->addChild('title', $item['title']); //add title node  '

The array was removed but the result was an empty '</title>'  
You can see it on my site: [link] http://zstreambox.com/mkttools/rssphp/t1.php [link]